# php multiple dropdown menu with same name can't get the value

Tags: php

okay, im new in this site also new in php and can't get the logic on this,

i have a product page that shows the name, quantity and an add to cart button in each row of product

i made this just cutted of some code

```
    while($showProducts = mysql_fetch_array($products))
            {
            $currenQuantity = $showProducts['current_quantity'];
            $prodid = $showProducts['product_id'];
    echo"<select name='quan'>";

                for ($x=0;$x<=$currenQuantity;$x++)
            {
                if($currenQuantity != 0)
                {
                echo "<option value=$x> $x </option>";
                }
            }
     echo"</select><br/>";
     }
```

now the problem is every time i tried to get the value by using $_POST['quan'] the value that i always get is the default value 1 even i select a different value of quantity of a certain product, and i'm blanked with ideas.

Comment: Where are you using `$_POST['quan']`? You mention that you've cut some code, but that seems relevant...

Comment: i put it in a variable everytime i clicked button add to cart like here. Michael's solution worked for me.

`code if(isset($_POST['addCart']))
   {
   $prodId = $_POST['addCart'];
   $_POST['quan'];
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same name for an input/select field in a form.
You have to specify a diffrent name or create an indexed array:

```
<select name="quan[$prodid]">
```

You can acces it via

```
$_POST['quan'][$prodid]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: has each of your product rows a select named 'quan'?
Then you're getting the last select named 'quan' in your POST data.

Prefix each of the quantities selects with name of the product, or some kind of a (scrambled) id.

Additionally:
If you don't want to have a 0 in your select, don't start the for loop with 0

```
for ($x=1;$x<=$currenQuantity;$x++)
```

if the current quantity is 0, the for loop doesn't get executed.

Comment: thanks, I fixed that mistake, yes you're right i always get the value of the last dropdown , btw I solved my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more selectboxes with the same name (quan) in one form, you are getting value of the last one.

You should change the selectbox definition to:

```
echo"<select name='quan[" . $prodid . "]'>";
```

then you can access the values using:

```
$_POST["quan"][$some_product_id]
$_POST["quan"][$another_product_id]
```