# How can I make simple PHP shopping cart robust and functional?

Tags: php, mysql, post, html-select, shopping-cart

I've made a very simple shopping cart for the first time.

How it works:

- Connects to MySQL Database.
- Queries the database using `SELECT` statement and displays the `prod_desc` in a html table
- It then allows you to select 'Quantity' using `<select>` tag and update your cart

**Here's problem #2:** You cannot select different 'Quantities' for items in your cart because the  tag is in the `while loop` i.e.

```
<?php while($cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 


    <form action="cart.php" method="POST">

     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <?php echo $cart["prod_desc"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>   
                <select name= "selectDropDown" >
                <option value="<?php echo $updatedValue; ?>" > <?php echo $updatedValue; ?> </option> 

                    <option value="2"> 2 </option> 
                    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                    <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                    <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                    <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                    <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                    <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="updated_value" value="update"/>
            </td>   

        </tr>
    </table>

    </form>


<?php 
} 

?>`
```

**Here's a screenshot of what happens when I select a quantity for one of the three items. (It selects the quantity for ALL items)**

[image]

**Potential solution I thought:** Create three different  tags outside of the `while loop` allowing you to select a 'Quantity' for each item in the cart, separately.

**Problem with my solution**: It's not robust and functional because if I want to add more then 3 products in my cart I'll have to code `<select>` tag myself for every new item in cart(!).

**What is the most optimal way to show the items in a cart retrieved from the database i.e. `prod_desc` and also users to pick a quantity for each item separately?**

**Here is my full code cart.php:**

```
<?php 

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    // If the update button is clicked and the if an option has been selected for the <select> tag.

    if(isset($_POST["updated_value"])) {

        if(isset($_POST["selectDropDown"])) {
            $updatedValue =  $_POST["selectDropDown"]; 
        }
    } else {
        $updatedValue = '1';
    }

?>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Description </th>
            <th>Quantity</th> 
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php while($cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> 

    <form action="cart.php" method="POST">

     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <?php echo $cart["prod_desc"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>   
                <select name= "selectDropDown" >
                <option value="<?php echo $updatedValue; ?>" > <?php echo $updatedValue; ?> </option> 

                    <option value="2"> 2 </option> <?php // HELP: HOW DO I MAKE THE LIST OPTIONS LOAD FROM DATABASE??? ?>
                    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
                    <option value="4"> 4 </option>
                    <option value="5"> 5 </option>
                    <option value="6"> 6 </option>
                    <option value="7"> 7 </option>
                    <option value="8"> 8 </option>
                    <option value="9"> 9 </option>
                    <option value="10"> 10 </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="updated_value" value="update"/>
            </td>   

        </tr>
    </table>

    </form>


<?php 
} 

?>
```

note: New to programming and PHP so I'm still learning 'how to think' about solving problems in code. I realize this is probably a simple problem for most StackOverFlow users.

Comment: It's more **Code Review** than **Stack Overflow**, I think...

Comment: Not really, the problem is clear: Same quantity is being selected for each item in cart.

Comment: possibly because all of the dropdown lists have the same name : see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837900/php-multiple-dropdown-menu-with-same-name-cant-get-the-value

Comment: But the title is *How can I make simple PHP shopping cart robust and functional?*, not *How can I fix my select field?*, I said it based on that.
Anyway, @PaulF s comment should help you out.